# Can't setup UITableViewCell in Xcode6 because "Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property .." warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I've created a new project in Xcode 6 and got warning, that I can't solve. I just want to setup a custom `UITableViewCell` as I did 1000 times in Xcode 5.

1. I've created a `UITableViewController` and a `UITableViewCell`
2. Dragged a `UILabel` into the `TableViewCell.h`

Now I'm getting the below warning in the `TableViewCell.h`

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'textLabel'
>   because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via
>   another property

Here's my `UILabel` that I dragged from Interface Builder

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

How can I solve this warning? I've never seen it before, it worked perfectly in Xcode 5.

Comment: @Kampai I don't want to use `@synthesize`, I've never did it. I've used always self.propertyName and never get any warning about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either change the property name so that you don't ovveride the existing one, or add

```
@synthesize textLabel = _textLabel;
```

It's better to name it in a different way.

Comment: So it's not an Xcode issue, instead I was wrong because textLabel was an existing property of UILabel that I duplicated with the new one?

Comment: Yes and to be more precise, it's because the original one is readonly and the one you are adding is readwrite.